GO-kratos can't find the protoc file when I use "make file" to generate go file
enter image description here
I have right path like:
enter image description here
I have an orther problem about file not found ,however they are in the same package.
this  is the archive.proto which use the User from user.proto, you can see it.
enter image description here
who can tell me why?

Please don't include images in SO questions (unless asking about GUI issues).  Most especially please don't include links to images hosted on other sites.  Edit your question and cut and paste the text into it, properly formatted as code blocks etc.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

use git bash shell to run the cmd.
the command in makefile may doesn't support cmd.
